# Can't bind selection to WPF Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I would like to have a ComboBox with two options "M" and "F" and set the selection from my code with a string of one of the values.  This seems so basic it's embarassing to even ask.  However, I haven't seen a single example that doesn't include 50 lines of code with custom classes, etc, etc.  To make things even easier, I want to prefill the two option in my XAML.  Why is this simple task making me feel like a mental midget?  This is what I have:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboGender"  >
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="M" Content="M"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="F" Content="F"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Code Behind:

```
cboGender.SelectedValue = "M";
```

Please help before I smash my computer and go back to ASP.NET development forever.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
cboGender.ItemsSource = new string [] { "M", "F" };
cboGender.SelectedItem = "M";
```

You need to set the ItemsSource to the collection of items. The ComboBox will then generate the ComboBoxItems for you.

Answer (score 1):

Add the [`SelectedValuePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath.aspx) and it works:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboGender" SelectedValuePath="Content" >
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="M" Content="M"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="F" Content="F"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

(*`SelectedValuePath="Tag"` would work, too, having the same data in two places seems quite redundant either way though*)

---

As a side-note, similar to Colin's answer you can set the items like this:

```xml
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="cboGender">
    <sys:String>M</sys:String>
    <sys:String>F</sys:String>
</ComboBox>
```

(*Both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue` work in this case*)

Comment: Good point, although setting SelectedValuePath="Content" feels a bit nasty!

Answer (score 0):

Try this - `cboGender.SelectedIndex = 0;` before smashing your system.. :)

Answer (score 0):

To a first approximation, if you ever manipulate WPF UI elements in code you're doing it wrong.  Sure, you can create a combo box with an "M" and an "F" and preset its selection:

```
<ComboBox>
  <ComboBoxItem>M</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>F</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBox.SelectedIndex>0</ComboBox.SelectedIndex>
</ComboBox>
```

But then what?  What do you do with that selection?  If your answer involves something like this:

```
if cboGender.SelectedValue == "M"
```

you're traveling down a road that will lead you to writing programs that are very hard to maintain.

If, on the other hand, you create a class to bind your UI to, like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public MyViewModelClass()
   {
      Gender = "M";
   }

   public IEnumerable<string> Genders { get { return new string[] { "M", "F" } };

   public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Then your XAML - assuming that somewhere along the line you've set the `DataContext` to an instance of `MyViewModel` - becomes:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Genders}" SelectedValue="{Binding Gender}"/>
```

Any other logic that uses the `Gender` property now looks at this class, not the UI.  So you can change the UI without affecting your logic, and vice versa.

(Note that while view models typically implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you only *need* to do this if you're going to be changing the `Gender` in your code and want the new values to be reflected in the UI.)